# Find IndexOf in C#

Tags: c#

How do i find `indexof()` from :

```
string value = "     50     ";
```

There are spaces...but I don't want to remove them using `SubString()` or `Replace()`...

I have to remove `leftindex` spaces until I get `"5"` and remove `rightindex` spaces after `"0"`.

Comment: Can you give some more context? the substring, replace and trim functions are built in for string handling seems you should use them.

Comment: I find it funny a indexof question is scored at -1

Answer (score 9):

String.Trim

Answer (score 5):

Just use `value = value.Trim();` and all spaces before and after "50" will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain it like this

```
value.Trim().IndexOf(whatever);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to build a logic for trimming space as there is already String.Trim() available in C#

value = value.Trim(); will give you "50"

Answer (score 1):

Today I learned something new about some of the little nuances of jQuery ajax calls and the JSON objects that are returned.

If you're familiar with, or have used jQuery ajax calls in your code, no doubt that the following code example looks typical to something you've seen prior:

For more answer visit this site :

http://net-2-media.com/test/c-indexof

Answer (score 0):

just fyi there is a .trimleft and a trimright  so you can get "50    " or "    50" respetivly